# Create a view that stays above all other views pushed inside the UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I want to know if its possible to create a view that will stay above all the other viewControllers that i push in my navigation controller.

I'm using storyboards in Xcode 5.0.2 with iOS6 plus platforms.

just like the UITabBarController works by nesting the navigation controller inside it so the tab bar stays at top no matter how many view controllers are pushed inside it. i want to create the same functionality but i can't use the tab bar controller due to the fact that its not very customizable and it doesn't look well for my app in iOS versions below iOS6. so my only option is to create my own view that will stay above a uinavigation controller.

I'm not sure if this is possible so kindly let me know if anyone knows a way to do this or anything similar. Any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: you can create view in appdelegate and add in window. then you have to make that view in front of navigation controller's view like [self.window bringsubviewtofront:yourview];

Comment: Sure, you can do this with a custom container controller. A tab bar controller is just one of Apple's canned container controllers -- you can create your own, and customize it how you want.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction. i'll let you know how it goes. :)